# Which database engine does Knowledge Flow's Obtain 24/7 product use?

Tags: c, object-oriented-database

I have been given the unenviable task of cleaning up after a developer who up and disappeared after failing to deliver on a project involving integrating Knowledge Flow's Obtain 24/7 with my client's back office systems.

My client own's the source code to the Obtain 24/7 product and has had it extended by some of Obtain 24/7's original developers on a consulting basis.  Unfortunately, they all had a falling out some time ago and are unavailable as a resource...

The product appears to be implemented (in C) using an object database that was either hand-rolled or white-labeled.  I am hoping someone out there knows something about it and can point me to a source a developer documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the underlying is a primitive custom database with features of both ISAM and object databases.  It was developed specifically for the Obtain 24/7 data center inventory management tool.  It was developed in the late 80's for the MS-DOS platform and has endured long past the expectation of the original developers.